# Android BLE: Add service data without UUID

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Is there any way to advertise data via BLE without UUID to use the rest of the space and maybe use some other way to uniquely identify our data instead (some string)?

Comment: Manufacturer specific data packet may include any payload. There is no requirements that it MUST have UUID.

Comment: And the integer? Where does it exactly fall and how much memory does it take?

Comment: Bluetooth Core Specification answers on all your questions.

Comment: Core Specification Supplement contains all advertising data variants.

Answer (score 1):

try to look at Eddystone beacons format